# jQuery - if statement excluding certain inputs

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a problem with an if statement but I can't get the code right.

I have multiple `divs` on a page with form elements. I have a reset button that clears all input fields via `.val(" ")` but I need to exclude `input[type=button]` somehow.

I don't have much knowledge around if statements and the formatting is definitely going wrong somewhere.

```
<!-- Reset only current div -->
$('.reset_form').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parents("div.menu_creation_form").find("input").val('');
    if () {
        $(this).parents("div.menu_creation_form").find("input[type=button]").val();
    }
    else() {
        // do nothing
    }
});​
```

Comment: You're missing the condition in your if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only select text inputs using the same kind of [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/):

```
$(this).parents("div.menu_creation_form").find("input[type=text]").val('');
```

However, this won't work if you don't explicitly set the `type` attribute equal to `text`. If you leave the type attribute out, the default value will be used and a textbox will be rendered, but it won't be found by this select. To get around this, you can use the `:text` selector:

```
$(this).parents("div.menu_creation_form").find("input:text").val('');
```

The latter method is a little slower though, I think.

Comment: You beauty, damn I should've thought of that. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You do not need if-else in the first place.. Try this

```
  $(this).parents("div.menu_creation_form").find("input:not([type=button])").val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="menu_creation_form">
    <input type="button" value="Clear" class="reset_form" />
    <input type="text" value="Jim" />
</div>
```

​jQuery:

```
​$('.reset_form').click(function() {
    $('input').not('[type="button"]').val('');
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

A Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/kuu26/1/

The key is using the [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).  No need for an `if` at all.

Comment: The `.each(...)` iteration is unnecessary, just call `.val('')` directly on the jQuery collection.

Comment: Excellent, didn't know that.  Updated!